# Windows shows my Ubuntu partitions, but cannot read them

Tags: windows, ubuntu, partitioning, windows-10

During installation of Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid Vervet, I created partitions for the Ubuntu filesystem as Ext2 using the Windows partitioning tool. I created partitions for the bootloader information and the Ubuntu file system. After Ubuntu installation, the Ubuntu partitions appear in Windows as local disks, but are not readable. When I try to open them, a message is shown stating that the partition is corrupted I am prompted to format the disk.

I don’t want to be able to access the Ubuntu filesystem from Windows.

- What is the cause of this?
- How can I hide this Ubuntu partition in Windows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Windows somehow decided to list this partition, but due to the fact that Windows lacked `ext2/3/4` filesystem driver it is not able to understand the contents of it. You can hide this in `Disk Manager` by deleting the assigned drive letter.

Or you can leave it as is and find a `ext2/3/4` driver for Windows so you can read (maybe and write) contents to the Linux partitions.

Comment: I would be careful about Windows drivers for Linux filesystems, especially if you want to write to them.

Answer (score 1):

The solution offered by Maxthon Chan will work; however, there is probably a better solution. To understand why it's a better solution, you must first understand the cause of the problem....

Since your question is tagged for Windows 10, my guess is the disk in question uses the GUID Partition Table (GPT). If you check the [Wikipedia article on GPT,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) you'll see that Windows data partitions have a type code of EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7, whereas Linux data partitions have a type code of 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4. Your partitioning procedure used Windows tools, so the Linux partitions probably have the Windows type code. This means that Windows thinks that the Linux partitions are Windows partitions. Thus, the better solution to the problem is to change the type codes of the partitions in question. Windows will then ignore the Linux partitions. This solution is superior to using Disk Manager in Windows because the Disk Manager solution applies to a single Windows installation -- if you need to use a Windows emergency disk or if you re-install Windows, the Linux partitions will show up again as damaged Windows partitions and be vulnerable to accidental damage.

To change the type code, you can use either of at least two classes of programs:

- In GParted and `parted`, you can remove the "msftdata flag" from the partition. This "flag" is libparted's way of identifying Windows data partitions.
- In GPT fdisk (`gdisk`, `cgdisk`, or `sgdisk`), you can change the type code from 0700 to 8300. These are the type code abbreviations that GPT fdisk uses for Windows and Linux data partitions, respectively.

Note that my answer is based on the assumption that the disk uses GPT. If it's an MBR disk, it's likely that something analogous could be done using the Linux `fdisk` tool, but changing the type code from 07 to 83. AFAIK, fixing this problem on an MBR disk is not possible with GParted or `parted`, although I'm not 100% positive of that. *Do not* use GPT fdisk on the disk if it's an MBR disk, since GPT fdisk will convert it from MBR to GPT form.